# Coldfusion 9 with Apache 2.2 not serving webpages

Tags: windows, apache, coldfusion, windows-server-2012, coldfusion-9

My environment
Coldfusion 9.0.2 (Multi instance mode over jrun4)
Apache 2.2
Windows Server 2012

Problem: Coldfusion and Apache are up and running but Apache is not connecting to CF.

What have I done till now:

1. Installed and configured CF9 and Apache 2.2
2. Ran the web configuration tool and Added Apache as the web server for CF applications.
3. Verified the contents of my httpd.conf file. They are:

   ```
   # JRun Settings
   LoadModule jrun_module "C:/JRun4/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so"
   <IfModule mod_jrun22.c>
       JRunConfig Verbose false
       JRunConfig Apialloc false
       JRunConfig Ignoresuffixmap false
       #JRunConfig Serverstore "C:/JRun4/lib/wsconfig/1/jrunserver.store"
       #JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51000
       JRunConfig Ignoresuffixmap false
       #JRunConfig Errorurl url <optionally redirect to this URL on errors>
       #JRunConfig ProxyRetryInterval 600 <number of seconds to wait before trying to reconnect to unreachable clustered server>
       #JRunConfig ConnectTimeout 15 <number of seconds to wait on a socket connect to a jrun server>
       #JRunConfig RecvTimeout 300 <number of seconds to wait on a socket receive to a jrun server>
       #JRunConfig SendTimeout 15 <number of seconds to wait on a socket send to a jrun server>
       AddHandler jrun-handler .jsp .jws .cfm .cfml .cfc .cfr .cfswf
   </IfModule>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/JRun4/servers/development/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war" 
       ServerName DEVELOPMENT 
       ErrorLog logs/error-development.log 
       <IfModule mod_jrun22.c>  
           JRunConfig Verbose true  
           JRunConfig Serverstore "C:/JRun4/lib/wsconfig/1/jrunserver.store" 
           JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51000
        </IfModule> 
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. made sure that the JRunProxyService is enabled for this instance:

   ```
   ...
       <attribute name="activeHandlerThreads">500</attribute>
       <attribute name="backlog">500</attribute>
       <attribute name="deactivated">false</attribute>
       <attribute name="interface">*</attribute>
       <attribute name="maxHandlerThreads">1000</attribute>
       <attribute name="minHandlerThreads">1</attribute>
       <attribute name="port">51000</attribute>
       <attribute name="threadWaitTimeout">300</attribute>
       <attribute name="timeout">300</attribute>
   ...
   ```

After all these steps, when I go to http://localhost:51000/cfide/administrator/index.cfm,
The page just keeps loading and eventually there is a timeout.

Is there any step that i am missing here?

Comment: 1. Has CF even been started? It can be ran on the command line or even better, as a service 2. I don't think `.so` works in Windows 3. If ColdFusion is running you should be able to hit its built in web server,

Comment: CF is running and we have been using the built in server for development since 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved. 
We figured that the location of the DocumentRoot had to be within `apache2/htpd/..`

Once the files were copied and DocumentRoot updated for each virtual host in `httpd.conf`, everything started working as expected.

Thank you to the community for time and effort invested to view and answer this query!